# Is anyone using Arquillian cube in production?

Tags: jboss-arquillian

As in, is anyone using it to test production software? I'm trying to set up some tests with it, but I'm running into a lot of dead-ends where it would be very useful to see how someone else is using it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know several companies that they are using it. If you can explain some of the problems, I can try to help you on that.